# Parameter returns error because it was referenced in an inner subexpression

Tags: reporting-services, filter, ssas, ssms, mdx

I've created a simple query in MDX to lookup a value. When i use this it works:

```
With
MEMBER [Measures].[dummy] as 1

select non empty {
[Measures].[dummy]
} on columns,
non empty {
except([Product].[Code].members, [Product].[Code].[All])
* except([Product].[Description].members, [Product].[Description].[All])
} on Rows

FROM 
(SELECT Filter([Product].[Description].[Description].Members, 
(InStr(1,[Product].[Description].CurrentMember.member_caption,"502080")>0)) 
ON COLUMNS  
FROM [Cube])
```

but when i try to make this dynamic for use with MSRS it gives me an error:
"The SearchFor parameter could not be resolved because it was referenced in an inner subexpression"

This is my code with parameter:

```
With
MEMBER [Measures].[dummy] as 1

select non empty {
[Measures].[dummy]
} on columns,
non empty {
except([Product].[Code].members, [Product].[Code].[All])
* except([Product].[Description].members, [Product].[Description].[All])
} on Rows

FROM (
 SELECT StrToMember
 ("Filter([Product].[Description].[Description].Members, 
   (InStr(1,[Product].[Description].CurrentMember.member_caption," + StrToMember(@SearchFor) + ")>0))") 
 on Columns

FROM [Cube])
```

Who knows how to get around this error? Please point me into the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my report would not show the data i retrieved with my MDX query. I started over with a new dataset:

```
With

MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Product].[Description].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Product].[Description].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Product].[Description].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 


select {
[Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
} on columns,

EXCEPT([Product].[Description].MEMBERS,[Product].[Description].[All]) * 
EXCEPT([Product].[Code].MEMBERS,[Product].[Code].[All]) 
  ON ROWS 
 FROM ( SELECT FILTER ([Product].[Description].Members, 
 (InStr ([Product].[Description].CurrentMember.Name, 
@SearchFor) <> 0)) ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube])
```

After adding a new tablix in my report the filter works as expexted. I still have no idea why my previous MDX wasn't working with the report.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you use the parameter is as a simple string, not as a member reference. Hence, just leave away the `StrToMember` so that the `FROM` clause gets

```
FROM 
(SELECT Filter([Product].[Description].[Description].Members, 
(InStr(1,[Product].[Description].CurrentMember.member_caption, @SearchFor)>0)) 
ON COLUMNS  
FROM [Cube])
```

It is difficult to check this without access to your cube.
However, to check the logic of the expression, you could issue a query like this:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[test0] as
     @SearchFor
     MEMBER Measures.[test1] as
     InStr(1,[Product].[Description].CurrentMember.member_caption, @SearchFor) > 0
SELECT { Measures.[test0], Measures.[test1] } on columns,
       {
       [Product].[Description].[ABC],
       [Product].[Description].[DEF],
       [Product].[Description].[GHI],
       [Product].[Description].[JKL]
       } on rows
  FROM [Cube]
```

You should replace the product list with some products really existing in your cube, some which fulfill the search criteria, and some that do not. Then you should be able to see `True` and `False` in the last column, depending if the match with the search criteria is successful or not. And the column to the left of it should display your search parameter in all rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i try this i still get the same error :-(

Comment: I checked the code and it runs without the error, but now i don't get any result back.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was able to solve the problem by myself. Started over from scratch, because i was still getting no results with you're latest solution.